# Unnexpected Behaviour From Software UART On ATtiny84A AVR

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, uart, attiny

I am trying to implement a software UART for the ATtiny84A, as it does not come with a UART out of the box.

The following is an example of the UART TX:

```c
DDRB  |= (1 << DDB0); // Set the pin on Port B0 to be an output for UART TX.
PORTB |= (1 << PORTB0); // Default the pin to HIGH for the idle high of the UART

void uart_tx(uint8_t *transmit_data)
{
    uint8_t string_length = strlen(transmit_data);
    for (uint_8t character = 0; character < string_length; character++) // Separate the string into characters.
    {
        PORTB &=~ (1 << PORTB0); // Send a start bit by bringing the UART TX low.
        timer_delay(); // Extra function that generates a delay to generate the appropriate baudrate.
        
        for (uint8_t character_bit = 0; character_bit < 8; character_bit++) // Separate the character into bits.
        {
            if ((1 << character_bit) & transmit_data[character]) // 
            {
                PORTB |= (1 << PORTB0); // Transmit a logical one
                timer_delay(); // Aforementioned delay
            } else {
                PORTB &=~ (1 << PORTB0); // Transmit a logical 0
                timer_delay(); // Aforementioned delay
            }
        }
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB0); // Transmit a stop bit by bringing UART tx High.
        timer_delay(); // Aforementioned delay
    }
}

uart_tx("ab");
```

What I would expect as an output is

```
0100001101 0010001101
```

however, what I am actually getting is shown in the following
[image: UART Waveform On Oscilloscope]

which in terms of bits is

```
00001000011010010001101...
```

Taken as a whole, it has little meaning, but upon closer inspection, parts of it *are* correct. What is wrong about it is the `000` inserted at the beginning, so a more accurate way of looking at it is

```
?...000 0100001101 0010001101
    ^ start bit?
```

More specifically: The last two frames are accurate, but mystery data is being inserted at the beginning.

What is very strange, is that If I implement this in a regular C program, it works as I would expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void uart_tx(unsigned char *transmit_data)
{
    for (unsigned char character = 0; character < strlen(transmit_data); character++)
    {
        printf("0");
        for (unsigned char character_bit = 0; character_bit < 8; character_bit++)
        {
            if ((1 << character_bit) & transmit_data[character])
            {
                printf("1");
            } else
              {
                printf("0");
            }
        }
        printf("1");
        printf(" ");
    }
}

uart_tx("ab");
```

outputs

```
0100001101 0010001101
```

as expected, so I am very perplexed as to what is going on here.

EDIT: Here is the delay related code

````
// Initializing the timer
TCCR0A  |=  (1 << WGM01);
TIMSK0  |=  (1 << OCIE0A);
OCR0A   =   52;

// timer function
void timer_delay(void)
{
    TCNT0   =   0;  // Reset the time
    TCCR0B  |=  (1 << CS01); // start the timer with /8 prescaler.
    while (!(TIFR0 & (1 << OCF0A)));    // Wait until the compare interrupt flag is set
    TIFR0   &=~ (1 << OCF0A);   // Reset the Compare flag
    TCCR0B  &=~ (1 << CS01);    // Stop the timer.
}
```
````

Comment: The idle state is `HIGH`. But why is the leftmost one third of the trace low ? If the start bit starts with a `HIGH->LOW` transition, your trigger (blue triangle) seems to be set for a `LOW->HIGH` transition. I think the extra `000` is coming from outside the function `uart_tx`. i.e., bet ween the line `PORTB |= (1 << PORTB0);` and the actual call to the `uart_tx` function. Can you show the lines in the code between the initial idle state setting and call to `uart_tx` ?

Comment: @AJN There's nothing in between those that would have any effect. In my code all there is is the initialization of a timer, and the `timer_delay()` function definition. I've even experimented with putting the idle state *immediately* before the function call, and still the same.

Comment: Is the observation persisting for multiple runs ? Perhaps some interrupt occurred just after the start bit was issued in the run where you captured the data ?

Comment: @AJN Correct, the observation persists through multiple runs. I have tried sending different data, and the same beginning persists: The early false start, or extended start. Also why do you say that it has a 1.5 bit time duration?

Comment: I'd strip the code down, only send the start and stop bits, see what it does. Gradually add stuff back in, see when it breaks.

Comment: @I have stripped it down to where I am just sending a stream of alternating bits, and no matter what, the first bit is always about 3.5 times the length of what it should be.

Comment: **1** Can you post the resulting assembly code? Perhaps something we cannot observe in the main `C` code. **2** Also, repeat a run with all interrupts disabled. **3** Also, a run with two successive calls to `uart_tx` to see if it occurs once per `uart_tx` function call or only once after uC reset.

Comment: Ignore my comment regarding the 1.5 duration. A quick search tells, me i was mistaken.

Comment: Congratulations for finding the only microcontroller out of millions on the market without UART. May I suggest that you switch to _any_ other microcontroller so that you get hardware support?

Comment: `strlen(transmit_data);` What if I want to send binary data instead of just text?

Comment: "what I am actually getting is shown in the following" Not related to your question, UART idles high. You bit-banged thing does not.

Comment: "// Initializing the timer TCCR0A  |= ..."  ... "TCCR0B = "  I don't know this part but aren't those 2 different timer channels? It would seem that you init timer A then use timer B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timer interrupt-flag is reset incorrectly. An interrupt flag is reset by writing a `1` to it, and not a `0`.

```c
TIFR0 &=~ (1 << OCF0A);
       ^ Incorrect
```

It should be

```c
TIFR0 |= (1 << OCF0A);
```

See Section 11.9.7 of the ATtiny24A/44A/84A datasheet (2020 version - Revision A) listed [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATtiny24A-44A-84A-DataSheet-DS40002269A.pdf)

> ...OCF0A is cleared by hardware when executing the cor-
> responding interrupt handling vector. **Alternatively, OCF0A is cleared by writing a logic one to
> the flag**...